# Long strings messing with div alignment/formation

Tags: html, css

I've got a list of users. And right now any user with a long name is messing with the alignment/ formation.

I thought by setting a size to the name would do the trick:

```
.invitee .name{
  height: 50px;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

... Not the case.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B92LW/7/) to show you what I mean.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invitee class has an inline-block css. Elements that act as inline elements by default are vertical aligned to the center, you can add:

```
.invitee {vertical-align:top}
```

Then you can remove the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/B92LW/23/

PD: inline-block doesn't work in old browsers like IE7. You can try adding this hack:

```
.invitee {
  display:inline-block; *display:inline; *zoom:1
}
```

Comment: Did the trick! Also, thanks for the explanation, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use overflow:
`overflow:hidden;`

this will hide everything which is bigger than that size.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/enve/B92LW/9/

Firstly define the height of `.invitee` and add `position: absolute` to `.name`

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```